# LWJGL doesn't render anything

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am trying to learn how to use LWJGL3 and I just got to a state where I want to render something (a test quad for now). I have a class that represents a mesh where I set up the VAO with vertex, colour and indices buffers and another object later takes the mesh instance, retrieves its VAO ID and attempts to render it.

The problem I have is that no matter what I try, nothing renders in the window. I can change the background colour through the glClearColor() method but the quad never shows up.

The VAO set up:

```
vertexCount = indices.length;

vaoID = glGenVertexArrays();
glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

//Vertices
FloatBuffer verticesBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(positions.length);
verticesBuffer.put(positions).flip();

vboID = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * 4, 0);

//Colours
FloatBuffer colorsBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(colors.length);
colorsBuffer.put(colors).flip();

colVboID = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colVboID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorsBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * 4, 0);

//Indices
IntBuffer indicesBuffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(indices.length);
indicesBuffer.put(indices).flip();

idxVboID = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, idxVboID);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

//Unbind
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

The rendering code:

```
//Bind the shader
shaderProgram.bind();

//Bind the VAO
glBindVertexArray(mesh.getVaoID());

//Draw
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, mesh.getVertexCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

//Restore
glBindVertexArray(0);
shaderProgram.unbind();
```

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330

layout (location=0) in vec3 pos;
layout (location=1) in vec3 inColor;

out vec3 exColor;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1.0);
    exColor = inColor;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330

in vec3 exColor;
out vec4 fragColor;

void main()
{
    fragColor = vec4(exColor, 1.0);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you enabled `glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);` in the beginning?

Comment: One obvious problem is that you're never storing any data in `colorsBuffer`.

Comment: @NoRelect: This function is replaced in Core Profile with `glEnableVertexAttribArray`.

Comment: @RetoKoradi That's why I shouldn't copy-paste parts of code. But even after fixing it, it still won't render anything.

Comment: What are the coordinates of the quad?

Comment: @derhass The positions are: `-0.5, 0.5`, `-0.5, -0.5`, `0.5, -0.5`, `0.5, 0.5` and indices are: `0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2`

Comment: @elect That is what I'm trying to do here. Render a basic quad and when I get it working, work from that.

Comment: @elect This sample just creates a window with a background color. I have that. I started with this sample when making the whole project. My problem is in rendering a quad in that window.

Comment: Sorry, I always thought they did render an hello triangle there... Try hardcode the color in the fragment shader

Comment: @elect Tried that too, sadly to no effect

Comment: @FilipSmola: Those coords are only 2D. But in your `glVertexAttribPointer` calls, you tell the GL that there are 3 components per vertex. So either there is a mismatch between the actual data layout in the buffer and the pointers you set up, or you did skip the z coords in your comment.

Comment: @derhass Yes I skipped them and forgot to mention that in the comment. That was a stupid ovesight on my part, sorry. All of the z-coordinates are 0 and they are declared in the actual code. I just wanted to make the comment shorter by omitting unnecessary information

Comment: Take inspiration from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38025772/1047713) other answer of mine

Comment: @elect I tried some things from that answer but they did not help. Nothing with matrices is relevant to me, I didn't even get that far. The background color is working so it probably isn't a problem with OpenGL. I tried using the hardcoded vertex shader you had there but that didn't even link for me (link error with no further information). I will try asking on the lwjgl forums, they might have some other ideas about what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in the parts of code shown, but in the main loop that I copied from a book without thoroughly thinking through what it did. I ended up with a `glClear` call right before `glfwSwapBuffers` call, which cleared the buffer right before showing it.

Lesson of the day: don't just copy from a book, think thoroughly about what you're doing

(Thank you to the people of LWJGL formus for helping me discover this mistake)